# modify-config-helper.js:40env.run(generatorName).on("end", () => {^ TypeError: env.run(...).on is not a function

Tags: webpack

```
TypeError: env.run(...).on is not a function
   at modifyHelperUtil (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\utils\modify-config- 
   helper.js:40:25)
   at initializeInquirer (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack- 
   cli\lib\commands\init.js:22:10)
   at initialize (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\index.js:20:41)    
   at C:\Users\shekhd2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:45:26
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shekhd2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack- 
   cli\bin\webpack.js:514:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

my node: '14.15.5' npm: '6.14.11' BTW. I am new to web development and not sure if I have to install some different versions or not or if there is a compatibility issue with my version of node and webpack which i tried is npm i -g webpack-cli@2.0.14.

Comment: When does it occur? What framework are you using and did you bootstrap?

Comment: getting this when trying to use webpack. But it got resolved with new version of web pack npm i -g webpack-cli@3.3.2

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved after installing the new version of webpack.
npm i -g webpack-cli@3.3.2

Comment: Nice fix! Thanks for sharing